# SQL Server BCP tool

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to IMPORT data from EXPORTED Dat file from SQL Server in this way:

```
bcp "SELECT FieldName FROM [BaseName].[dbo].[TableName] where xxxxxx=16" 
    queryout Message_out.dat -n -Uusername -Sservername
```

When I try to import dat to sql server like this

```
bcp basename.dbo.tablename in "path\to\datfile.dat" -c -T
```

I get error:

> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unexpected EOF
>   encountered in BCP data-file

regards, Grigor.

Comment: You need a format descriptor file too.

Comment: Does this help ? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sqltools/thread/d31db86a-4b11-4b41-b64f-0179e64625c5

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly indicate the field and row terminators for your file, for example, if your file is comma delimited and each row is in a new line:

```
bcp basename.dbo.tablename in "path\to\datfile.dat" -c -T -r\n -t,
```

And if if there are any other peculiarities in the format of your file, use the options to help bcp understand your file format using the options. A detailed documentation is available at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

I see this question is old, but maybe it will help someone in the future...